Ensure dependent jobs run in the same self hosted agent
I have the following scenario, using YAML pipelines:

multiple self hosted agents
a stage in a pipeline with multiple jobs. These jobs can not be combined into a single job
the jobs depend sequantially on each other
the different jobs must run in the same agent

I have tried multiple approaches, but nothing seems to work.
Is there a recommended way to force dependent jobs to run in the same agent?
Note: I do not need them tied to a specific agent, but to the same agent. I actually want all agents to be used, but the jobs in the stage must run in a single agent. Other stages or other pipeline runs can run in other agents.
EDIT
Providing more context on why I need to use a single agent from the pool of agents:

One of the jobs needs to run in a self managed docker container because it needs to run in host networking mode and that conflicts with Azure's use of user networks
The other jobs are implementing different functionality, using off the shelf tasks in azure managed containers (my container does not have the capabilities to run those tasks, and therefore I need other jobs)
The assets generated in the job running in the self managed container are needed in the other jobs, and those assets are not shared to Azure Artifacts, preventing use by other jobs that run in other agents. I do not know how to share the artifacts that I generate to the Azure Artifacts repo, and I am not even sure the self managed container that I use to obtain those artifacts is capable of uploading to Azure Artifacts
The stage with multiple jobs is currently working, if I guarantee that the same agent is used. Currently I can guarantee that by having a single self-hosted agent in the pool, but as soon as I put more agents in the pool that guarantee breaks, and the jobs will fail.
Keeping my current architecture working when I move to using multiple agents in the pool would be very easy if I can enforce an agent for all the jobs in the stage


Are you using YAML or classic pipelines (UI based)? The jobs must run in the same agent? Or in the same machine/VM? Could you please provide a bit more context on why you need to run things this way?

@RuiJarimba added more context. I am using YAML pipelines. The jobs must run in the same agent for the reasons detailed (but in my case that also means the same machine, since I am planning on having a self-hosted agent per machine)

Regarding "The assets generated in the job running in the self managed container are needed in the other jobs (......) I do not know how to share the artifacts that I generate to the Azure Artifacts repo," - you can publish and download pipeline artifacts using both Microsoft and self-hosted agents. Not sure if this would fix your issue, though.

You can use demands and capabilities to ensure the same agent runs all jobs in a specific stage.
It's important to use a capability that is unique per build agent, such as Agent.Name:

First job will set an output variable with that value:
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CurrentAgent;isOutput=true]$(Agent.Name)"

And the remaining jobs will then use a demand based on that variable:
variables:
  CurrentAgent: $[ dependencies.{job-name}.outputs['{task-name}.CurrentAgent'] ]

pool:
  name: MyAgentPool
  demands: Agent.Name -equals $(CurrentAgent)

Working example
trigger: none

stages:
  - stage: A
    jobs:
      - job: jobA0
        displayName: A0
        pool:
          name: Default
        steps:
          - checkout: none
          - script: |
              echo "Running job using agent $(Agent.Name)"
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CurrentAgent;isOutput=true]$(Agent.Name)"
            name: setAgent
            displayName: 'Set current agent'

      - job: jobA1
        displayName: A1
        dependsOn: jobA0
        variables:
          CurrentAgent: $[ dependencies.jobA0.outputs['setAgent.CurrentAgent'] ]
        pool:
          name: Default
          demands: Agent.Name -equals $(CurrentAgent)
        steps:
          - checkout: none
          - script: |
              echo "Running job using agent $(Agent.Name)"
            displayName: 'Display current agent'

      - job: jobA2
        displayName: A2
        dependsOn:
          - jobA0 # add the dependency on the job that sets the variable
          - jobA1
        variables:
          CurrentAgent: $[ dependencies.jobA0.outputs['setAgent.CurrentAgent'] ]
        pool:
          name: Default
          demands: Agent.Name -equals $(CurrentAgent)
        steps:
          - checkout: none
          - script: |
              echo "Running job using agent $(Agent.Name)"
            displayName: 'Display current agent'

      - job: jobA3
        displayName: A3
        dependsOn:
          - jobA0 # add the dependency on the job that sets the variable
          - jobA2
        variables:
          CurrentAgent: $[ dependencies.jobA0.outputs['setAgent.CurrentAgent'] ]
        pool:
          name: Default
          demands: Agent.Name -equals $(CurrentAgent)
        steps:
          - checkout: none
          - script: |
              echo "Running job using agent $(Agent.Name)"
            displayName: 'Display current agent'


One of he things that I tried is a variation of this approach, but it did not work. I will try again using your code as reference and will let you know


The assets generated in the job running in the self managed container are needed in the other jobs, and those assets are not shared to Azure Artifacts, preventing use by other jobs that run in other agents. I do not know how to share the artifacts that I generate to the Azure Artifacts repo, and I am not even sure the self managed container that I use to obtain those artifacts is capable of uploading to Azure Artifacts

You can publish and download pipeline artifacts from earlier jobs/stages in your pipeline or from another pipeline using both Microsoft-hosted and self-hosted build agents. You can also publish your artifact to a file share or make it available as a pipeline artifact.
This approach removes the dependency between the job that produces the artifacts and the job(s) that consume them.
Example pipeline
trigger: none 

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
  - stage: A
    jobs:
      - job: publishArtifacts
        displayName: 'Publish artifacts'
        steps:
          - script: |
              echo "Hello world" > $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/hello.txt
            displayName: 'Generate dummy artifact'

          - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
            inputs:
              targetPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) # specify the folder to publish
              artifactName: mySampleArtifact # specify the name of the artifact to be published

      - job: downloadArtifact
        displayName: 'Download artifact'
        dependsOn: publishArtifacts
        steps:
          - download: current # download artifacts produced by the current pipeline run
            artifact: mySampleArtifact # artifact name, as per the previous job

          # By default, artifacts are downloaded to $(Pipeline.Workspace)/<artifact-name>
          - script: |
              cat $(Pipeline.Workspace)/mySampleArtifact/hello.txt
            displayName: 'Display artifact content'

Please refer to the documentation for more details.

My problem is that I do not know if my custom container can run the PublishPipelineArtifact@1 task. I will try it, but the general question remains: what do you do if you are unable to upload artifacts in your job? How do you upload them in another job that has the necessary upload capability?

@blueFast Give it a try. Copy/paste my sample pipeline and check if it works or not ;-)
You can also use a file share, even though it probably complicates things a bit (I never used it). Check the link I've posted for more details.

@blueFast you mentioned a "custom container": FYI I ran the sample pipeline using a custom (aka self-hosted) Docker build agent, running on my machine.

@blueFast, Using "Publish and download pipeline artifacts" should be the best way to pass artifacts from one job to the subsequent jobs or subsequent pipelines.

@blueFast, As far as I can see, the tasks PublishPipelineArtifact@1 and DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 do not have any special requirements on the running environment. They are commonly available. And you just need to ensure that the agent versions of your self-hosted agents are 2.199.0 or greater.

@blueFast, When using a custom container to run a container job, the two also can work as normal.

@BrightRan-MSFT "When using a custom container to run a container job, the two also can work as normal": no, my container is self managed because azure containers mount user networks and that conflicts with my need for host networking mode. It is described in my question

@BrightRan-MSFT : "They are commonly available. And you just need to ensure that the agent versions of your self-hosted agents are 2.199.0 or greater. ". I am not giving any indications about the containers that I am running my tasks into. For all that is known, they are incapabla of running anything. The only constraint that I am giving is that they leave artifacts in the host running the agent, and therefore I need to run other tasks to collect those artifacts in the same agent. The containers that I use fo testing are highly incapable.

@RuiJarimba "Copy/paste my sample pipeline and check if it works or not ;-) You can also use a file share, even though it probably complicates things a bit (I never used it). Check the link I've posted for more details." I am sure that your particular example works, but your example does not have a raspberry pi running a modified arm64 agent connected to a DUT running an incapable arm64 container. I would need to adapt your example for testing on my environment, and as of now I have no time.

@blueFast artifacts will be stored at the Azure DevOps level, not in the agent container/machine. As I already mentioned, copy/paste my sample pipeline and check if it works or not. It doesn't take more than 5 or 10 minutes to test it.

@RuiJarimba you are still assuming that my jobs can upload or download at the azure devops level, which they can not. Therefore that solution is not going to help me.

@blueFast, All right. Maybe, you need to try the way mentioned in another answer.
